# SimpleHTMLDOM Parser does not pick-up img tags in <body>

Tags: simple-html-dom

I've been playing around with SimpleHTMLDOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) which is a great tool, however, I've been running into a problem collecting img elements from inside the body.  This is best illustrated through an example:

Here are 2 URL's of the same image.  I run the following code on these URLS respectively:

```
$html = $this->DOMParser->file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('img') as $element){
   print($element->src);
}
```

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/412/71banksy89789ll7.jpg/

(SHTMLD picks up the images here)

and

http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/412/71banksy89789ll7.jpg

(SHTMLD picks up nothing)

I've tried for a few days now to figure out what's going on, but the only different in this example would be in the html tags.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second url is pointing to an jpeg file directly, instead of a html page holding img tags. SimpleHTMLDOM Parser can only parse html pages, so it won't work when you fed it an image file instead of a html page.

Comment: You're absolutely right. For some reason I was taking the jpg path and putting it into my browser and looking at the content of the page and wondering why I couldn't get the img tag.  I think I need to unplug for a bit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Your second URL is not HTML, Its a Jpg!  :)